# Add custom drop down arrow to "select" input

Tags: html, css

I want to make a custom drop down menu ("select" menu), but I can't figure out how to add the icon that indicates that it is a drop down menu (the downwards facing ^ icon) I am looking for just a simple arrow and nothing special and am wondering if there is already a built in icons I can use, and if not how I make a custom one appear.

Comment: Hope this link helpful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/qhCsJ/4120/

Answer (score 0):

One option I recommend is to use HTML, here is a collection of HTML arrow symbols :

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/

Simple, clean, and SEO friendly.
Also, any library of SVG icons can make it.

Answer (score 0):

enter a url of the icon you want inside the brackets.

```
<select style="background: url() no-repeat right #ddd;"/>
```

eg:

```
 <select style="background: url() no-repeat right #ddd; background-position-x: 244px;"/>
```

also set a background position correctly

Comment: Your HTML tag is incomplete and your second example is not even a tag.  Please improve your answer

Comment: Hi @Emobe I have edited the code, Thanks for your comment